# Show one specific result in a list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Singlecountry = ({searchedCountries, setWeather, weather}) => {
  const weatherName = searchedCountries[0].capital
console.log(weather)
  
  useEffect(() => {
 

    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${weatherName}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
      .then(response => {
        const apiResponse = response.data;
        console.log(apiResponse)
        console.log(`Current temperature in ${apiResponse.name} is ${apiResponse.main.temp - 273.15}℃`);
    setWeather([apiResponse])
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
  }, [])
  
  return(
  <div>
  capital: {searchedCountries.map(c => <p>{c.capital}</p>)}
  area: {searchedCountries.map(c => <p>{c.area}</p>)}
  <h2>Languages</h2>
  <ul>
  {
    searchedCountries.map(c =>
      
        <ul>
          {Object.values(c.languages).map(l => <li>{l}</li>)}
        </ul>
     
    )
  }
</ul>
  {searchedCountries.map(c => <img src={Object.values(c.flags)[0]} alt="" /> )}
  <h3>Weather</h3>


        </div>
  )
}

const Countries = ({ searchedCountries, handleClick, show, setWeather, setCountries, weather}) => {
  if (searchedCountries.length >= 10) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>too many countries to list, please narrow your search</p>
      </div>
    )
  } 
  if (searchedCountries.length === 1) {
    return (
 <Singlecountry searchedCountries={searchedCountries} setWeather={setWeather} weather={weather}/>
    )
  }
  if (show === true) {
    return (
      <Singlecountry searchedCountries={searchedCountries} setWeather={setWeather} />
    )
  }
  return (
    <ul>
    {searchedCountries.map(c => <li>{c.name.common}<button onClick={handleClick} >show</button></li>)}
  </ul>
  )
}


const App = () => {
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
const [newSearch, setNewSearch] = useState('')
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
const [weather, setWeather] = useState('')


const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
  setNewSearch(event.target.value)
}

const handleClick = () => {
 setShow(!show)
}

const searchedCountries = 
countries.filter(c => c.name.common.includes(newSearch))

useEffect(() => {
  axios
  .get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
  .then(response => {
    setCountries(response.data)
  })
}, [])


  return (
    <div>
<div><p>find countries</p><input value={newSearch} onChange={handleSearchChange} /></div>
<div>
  <h2>countries</h2>
  <Countries searchedCountries={searchedCountries} handleClick={handleClick} show={show} setCountries={setCountries} setWeather={setWeather} weather={weather}/>
</div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default App
```

In this React App, the user searches for information on countries which the app gets from a fetch request to an API.

If there are between 1 and 10 matches - it displays just the name of the country along with a button saying "show", like this: [image: List of results]

On clicking the show button, I would like to display more in depth information specific to that country, like so: [image: Single Result].

However, when I click "show" - it displays all the information for all the countries beginning with "D", rather than the single country, like so: [image: Too many countries].

Does anyone know of a way to just display the information for one country when clicking the "show" button?

Thanks.

Comment: Because you have a global `show` variable to show/hide all the countries. Make it a `per component` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a boolen variable to show a country, you need to use an identifier for that country (like id or name). But for simplicity, you can use the index in the `searchedCountries` array. In your App component

```
const [activeCountryIndex, setActiveCountryIndex] = useState(null);
```

Then pass `activeCountryIndex` to the `Countries` compoment. And inside it you need to map the countries array, not inside the `Singlecountry` component. Then check the index of the country and `activeCountryIndex`, show it if they are equal.

Comment: Could you post a step by step guide? - I am new to React so I don't know how to add an identifier to the country or use an "index" in the searchedCountries array. I have added the const [activeCountryIndex, setActiveCountryIndex] but do not know how to check whether this index is the same as the country.